# Jquery mobile, cordova and 'old page' after changeorientation

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, orientation

I have simple 'page switcher' after changeorientation event.

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function(e){
        var or = null;
        if($(window).height() > $(window).width()){
            or = "portrait";
        } else{
            or = "landscape";
        }
        if(or === 'portrait'){
            $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
        } else if(or === 'landscape'){
            $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
        }

});
```

For example.

1. Start app on portrait
2. Page 1 loaded
3. Changing orientation to landscape
4. IMPORTANT! Page 1 rescaling to other orientation
5. Page 2 loaded on landscape orientation.

And I have a question. Do you have any ideas how can I prevent step 4? I want to something like this

1. Start app on portrait
2. Page 1 loaded
3. Changing orientation
4. Only Page 2 on landscape (without this rescalign Page1)

I've tried .hide() on activePage, but same result (First rescaling Page1 to landscape, after hide)

Comment: As per official jquery api documentation, jQuery.mobile.changePage is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and will be removed in 1.5.0. Use the pagecontainer widget's change() method instead.

Comment: But this is not resolve my problem. I need do some action after 'oreinatationchange' but before 'rescaling to other orientation'

Comment: Still dint get your actual issue.